# Linux QGIS disappeared

Tags: qgis, linux

Linux Mint 17.2
Just came to fire up QGIS after a couple of days doing other stuff and the launcher is not on my panel and the program is not listed in the Applications menu.

Presumably something I have done has removed it, but there is still a directory .qgis2 in my user directory. I've looked in various places and can't see any QGIS-related stuff.

I had been (having trouble with) installing LAMP and related stuff, which I uninstalled & installed XAMPP. The only system change I can think of is the LAMP uninstall removed QGIS? This is the command I used:

```
for pkg in dpkg -l *apache* *mysql* phpmyadmin | grep ^ii | awk '{ print $2 }'; do sudo apt-get -y purge --auto-remove $pkg; done;
```

Any ideas? Any log that I can see what might have happened?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing? Obvoiusly your command deleted too much packages.

Comment: Maybe the Apache2 in LAMP is used for qgis-server package.

Comment: what does `apt-cache policy qgis` return?

Comment: dcmi this. Even to me it doesn't look good... 'code' qgis:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.14.3+dfsg-2~trusty1
  Version table:
     2.14.3+dfsg-2~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.1-2build2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Pack ,'code'

Comment: AndreJ, not yet. probably will have to but hoping I can reinstate the packages.  This was the first time (on Linux) that I had the GRASS & SAGA tools working -all my previous Lx installations over the years never worked, only on W7. I had been hoping to defer the pain until QGIS 3 comes out.

Comment: I've stopped pursuing the reinstating route & need to get QGIS working/reinstalled.